# How do you make your model's database portable in CakePHP?

Tags: database, cakephp, primary-key, portability

I'm not very familiar with cake.. So here's my questions.. we're developing an app on mysql, but it may eventually need to deploy to mssql or oracle. How do we make sure that we won't have strange problems with our primary keys? In mysql they are AUTO INCREMENT columns but IIRC in oracle you need to use sequences... is there a way to make this a transparent change? Am I over thinking it?

Does anyone have experience with switching database vendors on a cakephp app? any pointers or things to keep an eye out for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Cake database config file you choose your driver (see http://book.cakephp.org/view/40/Database-Configuration).  Then, if you set your PK (which will also be your A_I column if using MySQL) with the fieldname `id`, Cake will automatically handle the auto_increment insertion.  I would presume (NB: haven't tried Cake w/ something else) that Cake will take care of A_I columns in something like Oracle.

Cake uses its own DB abstraction layer -- but the included abstractions cover quite a bit, and it will perform as specified (i.e. it'll handle your auto increment stuff for you).

In short, you're probably overthinking.  That said, I would mock up a little cake app, then try switching databases behind it (change your db config and your app should automagically switch over).

HTH,
Travis

Answer (score 1):

The following practices work great for me

I use cake schemas ( I tend to set up 1 schema file for each group of models. I.E. User, Role, Profile might all be in one UsersSchema file )

Also take a look at using the debuggable.com FixturesShell - it allows you to import test case fixtures into the live database. Great for setting up that initial group of users and roles from the schema file.

Also, if you set your 'id' field to VARCHAR(36) instead of INT(#) cake will automatically use UUID style id's. This means you have a FAR FAR lower chance of your data having id value collisions if you need to move the data to another application or server.

The fixtures shell also has a command line tool for generating uuids ( so you can add them to your $records variable in the fixture for insertion etc. )

In summary - Use the CakeSchema schemas shell, the fixtures shell from debuggable.com and UUID values for your id's and it should give you a portable structure creation tool, a portable data insertion tool, and a portable id field format.

http://github.com/felixge/debuggable-scraps/tree/fd0e5ad625cb21f5ba16e6b186821a5774089ac7/cakephp/shells/fixtures

http://api.cakephp.org/class/schema-shell

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using "cake schema" to manage your DB.. This will handle all the DB specific stuff when you create your database.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/735/Generating-and-using-Schema-files